# THREE.JS | glTF Morphing targets glTF issue

Tags: animation, three.js, glsl, gltf, kinematics

I'm trying to tweak [Particle Dreams demo](https://github.com/nopjia/particles) by Nop Jiarathanakul and port it to newer THREE.JS version and glTF format.

While the code has complex structure, I couldn't publish as a snippet, however the current state is available [here](http://vkuchinov.github.io/particleDreams_106/).

It works fine with horse model taken from THREE.JS examples while it's based on morph targets.

[image]

But, what if glTF doesn't have morph targets, since it's an old technology, and based on skeleton kinematics.

[image]

Pretty sure that I need to update `shaders/UVMapShader.vs.glsl`

```
varying vec3 vPos;

#ifdef USE_MORPHTARGETS
    uniform float morphTargetInfluences[ 4 ];
#endif

void main() {

#ifdef USE_MORPHTARGETS

    vec3 morphed = vec3( 0.0 );
    morphed += ( morphTarget0 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 0 ];
    morphed += ( morphTarget1 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 1 ];
    morphed += ( morphTarget2 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 2 ];
    morphed += ( morphTarget3 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 3 ];
    morphed += position;

    vPos = (modelMatrix * vec4(morphed, 1.0)).xyz;
#else
    vPos = (modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0)).xyz;
#endif

    vec2 drawUV = uv * 2.0 - 1.0;
    gl_Position = vec4(drawUV.x, drawUV.y, 0.0, 1.0);

}
```

Comment: glTF does support both morph targets and skeleton/bone animation.  But I'm not sure what your question is here, are you trying to get all of Particle Dreams into a single glTF?  That may prove quite challenging, with so many individually moving particles.

Comment: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Tutorials/blob/master/gltfTutorial/gltfTutorial_017_SimpleMorphTarget.md The reference says that 2.0 is now supports morph targets definition and horse.glb works pretty well with current code.